# Swift - update UIButton image from last photo in roll

Tags: swift, uibutton, camera-roll

I am trying to use the last image from the camera roll as the background image for my UIButton. When the view loads up the button shows the last photo correctly. But when I snap a picture the background image in the UIbutton is not updated. Here is the code I am using to get the last photo

```
func lastPhoto() {
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
    var fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: true)]
    if let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions) {
        imgManager.requestImageForAsset(fetchResult.lastObject as PHAsset, targetSize: self.view.frame.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: { (image, _) in
            self.rollBtn.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        })
    }
}
```

not sure if it is relevant, but here is the snippet of code I use to take the photo

```
    switch (camMgr.cameraOutputMode) {
    case .StillImage:

        camMgr.capturePictureWithCompletition({ (image, error) -> Void in

            if let capturedImage = image? {
                println("capture image")

                //animate button effect
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                    }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
                        println("inside")
                        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                        self.lastPhoto()
                })
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
                    self.buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
                        println("inside")
                        self.buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                        self.lastPhoto()
                })

            }
        })

    case .VideoWithMic, .VideoOnly:
        sender.selected = !sender.selected
        sender.backgroundColor = sender.selected ? UIColor.redColor() : UIColor.greenColor()
        if sender.selected {
            camMgr.startRecordingVideo()
        } else {
            camMgr.stopRecordingVideo({ (videoURL, error) -> Void in
                println(videoURL)
                if let errorOccured = error? {
                    UIAlertView(title: "Error occured", message: errorOccured.localizedDescription, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I am still new to this whole coding thing, please any help would be nice. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Where is all this code called, i.e. `viewDidLoad` or some initializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I am not sure you need to fetch the last photo. Just update the UIButton background image like so. Should give the effect you are after. Let me know if it fixed it.

```
       if let capturedImage = image? {
            println("capture image")

            //animate button effect
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
                    println("inside")
                    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            })
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
                self.buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
                    println("inside")
                self.buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
               self.rollBtn.setBackgroundImage(capturedImage, forState: .Normal)
            })

        }
    })
```